# Can the Raspberry Pi Pico handle 10V?

Tags: power-supply, power, raspberry-pi-pico

I am currently trying to restart a long forgotten project of mine, because it started to bug a little. I now want to make the project more sophisticated (by not using jumper cables in "production").
Back then I used an Arduino Nano and input 10V over the VIN port. Now my question is, if the Raspberry Pi Pico can handle 10V input in its corresponding VIN pin (when I am right Arduinos VIN is the Raspberry's VSYS pin).

I searched in the datasheet and the max voltage is for the pin "VSYS Max 5.5V". Did I overlook something, or can't/shouldn't I really apply 10V?

(I am somewhat inexperienced with electronics, please keep that in mind.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### No, it can not

There's not much to say here. The Arduino Nano can do 10 volts (and more), but the Raspberry Pi Pico can only do up to 5.5 volts.

The [Arduino Nano](https://content.arduino.cc/assets/NanoV3.3_sch.pdf) runs internally on 5 volts and has a linear [LM1117](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1117.pdf) regulator that can handle voltages up to 15 volts. This regulator is not required if you power the board directly with 5 volts.

The [Raspberry Pi Pico](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/pico/pico-datasheet.pdf) requires a 3.3 volt internal supply voltage, and the external USB or battery power supply is stepped down by a [RT6150](https://www.richtek.com/assets/product_file/RT6150A=RT6150B/DS6150AB-04.pdf) switch-mode regulator, with a maximum input voltage of 5.5 volt.

Comment: A bummer, thank you for the answer! Maybe you are so kind and answer my followup question? When I have a 10V power source, I would have to use a voltage transformer, to convert the power to 5V, right?

Comment: @Moritz It has to be converted, correct, and there are many ways to do it depending on your requirements. Chapter 4.5 in the Pico datasheet has some details, and you might want to use a product such as this [buck converter](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4739) for simple and efficient conversion, and there are many more options if you look around. Almost every DYI place will have alternatives.

Comment: @Moritz Transformers are used for converting between AC voltages. Since the products you are talking about use DC power, you will have more luck looking for a DC-DC converter or buck converter.

Comment: @Vegard I meant a voltage regulator, sth like the L 7805 CV. In my native language, the direct transaltion of an voltage regulator is voltage transformer. I didn't check weather the translation made sende. Sorry for that. But to be sure, a voltage regulator is what I need?